# wrong values with Globalize.js decimal number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate some numbers on my asp.net mvc5 application with globalize.js plugin for jquery...

When i enter number with `,` as decimal separator, everything works fine as it should be.
When i enter it with `.`, number pass validation but this is wrong, and error should be thrown. I checked what's happening in jquery and found that line used to check number

```
var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
```

is returning wrong value. When i pass `1,25`, result is `1.25`. When i pass `1.25`, return value is `125`, instead of error...

I have declared

```
  Globalize.culture('sr-Latn-RS');
```

in my javascript and

```
<globalization culture="sr-Latn-RS" uiCulture="sr-Latn-RS" />
```

in web.config.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: are you talking about this plugin https://github.com/jquery/globalize ?

Comment: i'm not exactly sure is it this one, i got plugin from nuget following instructions on this page
http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.com/2012/09/globalize-and-jquery-validate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of exploring a problem, i finally found it in a "Handle Groups" part of ParseFloat function of jquery.globalize plugin.

```
integer = integer.split( groupSep ).join( "" );
```

line should be replaced with

```
integer = integer.split(groupSep).join(nf["."]);
```